# MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION.AllocationBase IMAGE_DOS_HEADER validity check

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm using VirtualQueryEx to loop through memory allocation within a process. However, for some odd reason when comparing the allocationbase to the valid IMAGE_DOS_HEADER signature / 'MZ' I get an access violation... Could someone point out what is not correct in my code?

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
do 
{
   if (VirtualQueryEx(handle, currentAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == 0) 
   {
      continue;
   }

   if (mbi.State & MEM_COMMIT && !(mbi.Protect & PAGE_NOACCESS) && 
         !(mbi.Protect & PAGE_PROTECT))
   {
      if (mbi.AllocationBase != nullptr)
      { 
         bool hasValidDosHeader = *(WORD*)mbi.AllocationBase == 
         IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE; //THIS CAUSES AN ACCESS VIOLATION 
      }
   }
   currentAddress += mbi.RegionSize;
} while(currentAddress < endAddress);
```

PS: I've also tried casting the AllocationBase to an IMAGE_DOS_HEADER* and then checking e_magic with IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE, which also causes an access violation...

Comment: Are you looking for information from the current process, or another process?  You can't dereference a pointer that doesn't belong to your process!

Comment: I'm looking for information from another process. If I can't dereference the pointer, how would I go about seeing if the allocation has a valid DOS header instead?

Comment: [ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader;
if (!ReadProcessMemory(handle, mbi.AllocationBase, &dosHeader, mbi.RegionSize, NULL)) {
 continue;
} Getting the IMAGE_DOS_HEADER like this and then checking for e_magic like so, bool hasValidDosHeader = dosHeader.e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE; would be correct then?

Comment: You want to read `sizeof(dosHeader)` bytes, not `mbi.RegionSize`.  And `continue` isn't the right way to handle errors, that will just hang the process as the same error occurs over and over.  And your loop condition appears to be back to front.  But, basically, yes.

Comment: @HarryJohnston - I will delete my answer if you post one.  I hadn't spotted your comments.

Comment: @mksteve, not a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VirtualQueryEx` returns information about the remote memory, but does not read it for you.

You need [msdn: ReadProcessMemory](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) to actually copy the memory from the remote process to your process in order to read the memory.

```
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION mbi;
do 
{
   if (VirtualQueryEx(handle, currentAddress, &mbi, sizeof(mbi)) == 0) 
   {
      break; // we can't continue in the loop, as we don't know the size.
   }

   if (mbi.State & MEM_COMMIT && !(mbi.Protect & PAGE_NOACCESS) && 
         !(mbi.Protect & PAGE_PROTECT))
   {
       if (mbi.AllocationBase != nullptr)
       { 
          IMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader; 
          if (ReadProcessMemory(handle, mbi.AllocationBase, &dosHeader, mbi.RegionSize, NULL)) {

              bool hasValidDosHeader = dosHeader.e_magic == IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE; 
          }
       }
   }
   currentAddress += mbi.RegionSize;
} while(currentAddress < endAddress);
```